# Fetch baseaddress of locally stored image with/without the use of AVFoundation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avfoundation

Instead of using AVCaptureSession, I have stored image in the resources folder of Xcode project. I need to fetch the baseaddress and all the related information of the image just as AVCaptureOutput does but without using AVCaptureOutput.

Or, if there is a way to use AVFoundation to fetch the same details but for locally stored image how would i do that?

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

used the following to fetch the information:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"something.jpg"];
NSData  *dataObj = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
CGImageRef cgImage = [image CGImage] ;
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage)
unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
NSLog(@"rawdata %u",rawData);
```

Facing one problem though, how would i take the log of rawdata . I am using %u for the same but it is returning some random number and since it is unsigned char, i should use %c but for %c, it is returning blank.